# ¿Cómo utilizar los Toasts de materialize?

Tags: php, javascript, pdo, materialize, alert

Quisiera cambiar el modelo de como mostrar mis 'mjs' de alertas para cuando hago un *insert*, *delete* y *update*. Quisiera cambiar estas alertas por los *Toasts* de *materialize*. Anexo el código con como hago para mostrar las alertas.

Link de matrerialize: http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html

**Método para insertar**

```
<!-- proceso para registrar-->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){


$sql = "SELECT cuentas FROM cuentas WHERE cuentas = :cuentas LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
$check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
$check->bindParam(':cuentas', $_POST['cuentas']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
$check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
$contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
if ($contador > 0) {
$check->closeCursor();

          $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado !";

}
else
{

$sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO cuentas (cuentas) VALUES (:cuentas)");
$sql->bindParam(':cuentas', $_POST['cuentas']);
$sql->execute();

      $successMSG ="¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !";

    }
  }
?>
```

**Mostrar mjs**

```
<!-- mostrar mjs -->
<?php
if(isset($errMSG))
{
  ?>
  <div id="element" class='col s5 card-panel blue lighten-2 right'>
  <h6 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
  <?php echo $errMSG; ?> <a href='#' class="black-text" id="hide">[X]</a>
  </h6>
  </div>
  <?php
 }
 else if(isset($successMSG))
 {
   ?>
   <div id="element" class='col s5 card-panel teal lighten-2 right'>
   <h6 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
   <?php echo $successMSG; ?> <a href='#' class="black-text" id="hide">[X]
  </a>
   </h6>
   </div>
  <?php
  }
 ?>           
  <!-- FIN VALIDACION -->
```

Comment: @A. Cedano a esto era lo que me referia

Answer (score 1):

puedes indicarle al error que sea tu toast de materialize

```
 $errMSG = "<script>
            Materialize.toast('¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado', 2500, 'rounded');
           </script> ";
```

donde el primer parametro es el mensaje, el segundo el tiempo de duracion y el tercero la clase que quieres colocarle.

no te olvides de importar el jquery y materialize css y js

Saludos , ojalá te sirva y te advierto que el mensaje quedará muy largo en tu pantalla .
puedes usar un "No disponible" o "usar otro" bye

Answer (score 0):

En tu mostrar mensaje puedes aplicarlo

```
<?php
if(isset($errMSG))
{
  ?>
  <a id="alerta" class="btn" onclick="Materialize.toast(<?php echo $errMSG; ?>, 4000)"></a>
<script>
   document.getElementById('alerta').click();
</script>
  <?php
 }
 else if(isset($successMSG))
 {
   ?>
   <a id="alerta" class="btn" onclick="Materialize.toast(<?php echo $successMSG; ?>, 4000)"></a>
<script>
   document.getElementById('alerta').click();
</script>
  <?php
  }
 ?>           
  <!-- FIN VALIDACION -->
```

Cargaras en mensaje en el primer parametro de Materialize.toast y lanzarás el evento click del elemento a.alerta.

(si lo puedes hacer desde php mucho mejor para que evitar combinar los lenguajes).